# html id completion

Tags: autocompletion, ins-completion

I'm familiar with vim's built in completion, one of the completion methods allow me to autocomplete filepaths.

I am working with a large html project where I need to reference filepaths along with id's that are located on that html page itself. To handle this type of completion I've had to resort to using an IDE, this is what the functionality looks like:

[image: html id completion]

Note that it's auto completing the id located in the file on the left. I am completely new to how I might go about this, but so far I've taken a look in the help system with `:help ins-completion-menu`, but I didn't notice any information on how to actually extend it.

How could I create this behavior in vim?

Answer (score 0):

Keyword completion can look in included files and open buffers. See the complete option and insert mode’s C-n/C-p.